Question about grape vines and keeping stray animals away
I have a grape vine and I noticed some cats have been peeing and defecating on the soil. Is my vine ruined or will the grapes be edible? How can I keep the cats away from my garden?

Yes, the grapes will be edible, but to keep cats off in the meantime, insert 'pea' sticks quite closely together to make a kind of obstacle course - pea sticks are quite thin, usually green and around 9-12 inches long. These will prevent them getting onto the soil in that area. Some people will use cut thorny or prickly branches laid on the ground to do the same job, or dig up an area elsewhere so the soil is loose and they'll go there instead.

The grapes will still be edible but the vine may not like being dosed with such high amounts of concentrated nutrients in the form of cat waste. As I understand it, there are sprays and other products designed to repel cats and dogs - your local garden center will likely have something that will work.

Electric fences are great for discouraging animals of any size up to (and including) bears. Even the smallest energizer is big enough for any home garden. I have one for my apiary, but I ran an extension to my vegetable garden and no more troubles with deer or racoons.
A shock is unpleasant (like a carpet shock) but causes no injury. I touched it once and my dog touched it once. We both decided once was enough.
